# MaskedTextBox for WinRT

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I'm looking for a MaskedTextBox for WinRT, I can't seem to find any... Does anybody know if such a textbox exists?

I found the one from ComponentOne, but that one is paid, and I'm looking for a free sollution.

If someone knows an open source sollution for Silverlight or Windows Desktop that **isn't** like over 2000 lines of code, I'm willing to look into it and try to convert it to WinRT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use a [behavior](http://blindmeis.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/wpf-masked-textbox-behavior/) instead of a maskedtextbox control. but honestly i dont know if this would work on WinRT

EDIT: here is my latest version

```
public class TextBoxInputMaskBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    private WeakPropertyChangeNotifier _notifier;

    #region DependencyProperties

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputMaskProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("InputMask", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxInputMaskBehavior), null);

    public string InputMask
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(InputMaskProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InputMaskProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PromptCharProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("PromptChar", typeof(char), typeof(TextBoxInputMaskBehavior), new PropertyMetadata('_'));

    public char PromptChar
    {
        get { return (char)GetValue(PromptCharProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PromptCharProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResetOnSpaceProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("ResetOnSpace", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxInputMaskBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool ResetOnSpace
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ResetOnSpaceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ResetOnSpaceProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    public MaskedTextProvider Provider { get; private set; }


    public TextBoxInputMaskBehavior()
    {
        //defaults
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObjectLoaded;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput += AssociatedObjectPreviewTextInput;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown += AssociatedObjectPreviewKeyDown;

        DataObject.AddPastingHandler(AssociatedObject, Pasting);
    }


    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= AssociatedObjectLoaded;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput -= AssociatedObjectPreviewTextInput;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown -= AssociatedObjectPreviewKeyDown;

        DataObject.RemovePastingHandler(AssociatedObject, Pasting);
    }

    /*
    Mask Character  Accepts  Required?  
    0  Digit (0-9)  Required  
    9  Digit (0-9) or space  Optional  
    #  Digit (0-9) or space  Required  
    L  Letter (a-z, A-Z)  Required  
    ?  Letter (a-z, A-Z)  Optional  
    &  Any character  Required  
    C  Any character  Optional  
    A  Alphanumeric (0-9, a-z, A-Z)  Required  
    a  Alphanumeric (0-9, a-z, A-Z)  Optional  
       Space separator  Required 
    .  Decimal separator  Required  
    ,  Group (thousands) separator  Required  
    :  Time separator  Required  
    /  Date separator  Required  
    $  Currency symbol  Required  

    In addition, the following characters have special meaning:

    Mask Character  Meaning  
    <  All subsequent characters are converted to lower case  
    >  All subsequent characters are converted to upper case  
    |  Terminates a previous < or >  
    \  Escape: treat the next character in the mask as literal text rather than a mask symbol  

    */
    void AssociatedObjectLoaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Provider = new MaskedTextProvider(InputMask, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        this.Provider.PromptChar = this.PromptChar;
        this.Provider.SkipLiterals = true;
        this.Provider.ResetOnSpace = this.ResetOnSpace;
        this.Provider.Set(AssociatedObject.Text);

        AssociatedObject.Text = GetProviderText();

        //seems the only way that the text is formatted correct, when source is updated
        //AddValueChanged for TextProperty in a weak manner
        this._notifier = new WeakPropertyChangeNotifier(this.AssociatedObject, TextBox.TextProperty);
        this._notifier.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(this.UpdateText);          
    }
    void AssociatedObjectPreviewTextInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        this.TreatSelectedText();

        var position = this.GetNextCharacterPosition(AssociatedObject.CaretIndex);

        if (Keyboard.IsKeyToggled(Key.Insert))
        {
            if(!this.Provider.Replace(e.Text, position))
            {
                System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(!this.Provider.InsertAt(e.Text, position))
            {
                System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
                return;
            }
        }

        var nextposition = this.GetNextCharacterPosition(position + 1);
        this.RefreshText(nextposition);
    }

    void AssociatedObjectPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Space)//handle the space
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            this.TreatSelectedText();
            var position = this.GetNextCharacterPosition(AssociatedObject.CaretIndex);

            if (!this.Provider.InsertAt(" ", position))
            {
                System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
                return;
            }

            this.RefreshText(AssociatedObject.CaretIndex + 1);
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Back && AssociatedObject.CaretIndex > 0)//handle the back space
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            //wenn etwas markiert war und der nutzer Backspace klickt soll nur das markierte verschwinden
            if(this.TreatSelectedText())
            {
                this.RefreshText(AssociatedObject.CaretIndex);
                return;
            }

            var denDavor = AssociatedObject.CaretIndex - 1;

            if(this.Provider.IsEditPosition(denDavor))
            {
                if (!this.Provider.RemoveAt(denDavor))
                {
                    System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
                    return;
                }
            }

            this.RefreshText(AssociatedObject.CaretIndex - 1);
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Delete)//handle the delete key
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            //wenn etwas markiert war und der nutzer Delete klickt soll nur das markierte verschwinden
            if (this.TreatSelectedText())
            {
                this.RefreshText(AssociatedObject.CaretIndex);
                return;
            }

            var position = AssociatedObject.CaretIndex;

            if (this.Provider.IsEditPosition(position))
            {
                if (!this.Provider.RemoveAt(position))
                {
                    System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
                return;
            }

            this.RefreshText(AssociatedObject.CaretIndex);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pasting prüft ob korrekte Daten reingepastet werden
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Pasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
        {
            var pastedText = (string)e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(string));

            this.TreatSelectedText();

            var position = GetNextCharacterPosition(AssociatedObject.CaretIndex);

            if (!this.Provider.InsertAt(pastedText, position))
            {
                System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
            }
            else
            {
                this.RefreshText(position);
            }
        }

        e.CancelCommand();
    }

    private void UpdateText(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        //check Provider.Text + TextBox.Text
        if (this.Provider.ToDisplayString().Equals(AssociatedObject.Text))
            return;

        //use provider to format
        var success = this.Provider.Set(AssociatedObject.Text);

        //ui and mvvm/codebehind should be in sync
        this.SetText(success ? GetProviderText() : AssociatedObject.Text);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Falls eine Textauswahl vorliegt wird diese entsprechend behandelt.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>true Textauswahl behandelt wurde, ansonsten falls </returns>
    private bool TreatSelectedText()
    {
        if (AssociatedObject.SelectionLength > 0)
        {
            this.Provider.RemoveAt(AssociatedObject.SelectionStart, AssociatedObject.SelectionStart + AssociatedObject.SelectionLength - 1);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void RefreshText(int position)
    {
        SetText(GetProviderText());

        AssociatedObject.CaretIndex = position;
    }

    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        AssociatedObject.Text = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) ? String.Empty : text;
    }

    private int GetNextCharacterPosition(int caretIndex)
    {
        var start = caretIndex;

        var position = this.Provider.FindEditPositionFrom(start, true);

        if (position == -1)
            return start;
        else
            return position;
    }

    private string GetProviderText()
    {
        //wenn noch gar kein Zeichen eingeben wurde, soll auch nix drin stehen
        //könnte man noch anpassen wenn man masken in der Oberfläche vllt doch haben will bei nem leeren feld
        return this.Provider.AssignedEditPositionCount > 0
                   ? this.Provider.ToDisplayString()
                   : this.Provider.ToString(false, false);
    }


}
```

Comment: looks promising, I'll take a look at it