# Enter PIN number in windows phone app 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Hi I have a text box in my windows phone app where the user can enter a pin number I can't have a password field cause it cannot be restricted to numbers. I need a the numbers to be visible as a "*".

Comment: Take a look at Masked textboxes, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545039/maskedtextbox-for-winrt That might just do the trick for you.

Comment: nope. it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a custom control for this: https://github.com/igorkulman/NumericPasswordBox